# plot_summs() change size of plotted regression coefficients

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, formatting, coefficients

I'm using `plot_summs()` from the `jtools` package to plot regression coefficients. I'm trying to make the plot big enough to see for a presentation and I figured out how to change the size of everything except the actual plotted coefficients (see the example plot below).

Anyone have any ideas how to make the plotted coefficients bigger?

```
#example data and models
states <- as.data.frame(state.x77)
fit1 <- lm(Income ~ Frost + Illiteracy + Murder +
         Population + Area + `Life Exp` + `HS Grad`,
       data = states, weights = runif(50, 0.1, 3))
fit2 <- lm(Income ~ Frost + Illiteracy + Murder +
         Population + Area + `Life Exp` + `HS Grad`,
       data = states, weights = runif(50, 0.1, 3))
fit3 <- lm(Income ~ Frost + Illiteracy + Murder +
         Population + Area + `Life Exp` + `HS Grad`,
       data = states, weights = runif(50, 0.1, 3))

# Plot all 3 regressions with custom predictor labels,
# standardized coefficients, and robust standard errors
testplot <- plot_summs(fit1, fit2, fit3, coefs = c("Frost Days" =
     "Frost", "% Illiterate" = "Illiteracy","Murder Rate" = "Murder"),
                   scale = TRUE, robust = TRUE)

#custom theme to format 
apatheme=theme_bw()+
theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
    panel.border=element_blank(),
    axis.line=element_line(),
    text=element_text(family='Helvetica'),
    legend.title=element_blank(), 
    axis.text=element_text(size=25),
    axis.title=element_text(size=15),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 20))


testplot  + apatheme + labs(x = "\n Beta Estimate \n ", y = NULL)
```

[image: Example plot (I want to change the size of the plotted coefficients)]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the height and width that you want. At the top of your code type this:

```
plot.new()
dev.new(width=5, height=4)
```

Adjust the width and height as needed.